# Kalman Filter with OpenCL

Tags: opencl, kalman-filter

I'm a new OpenCL programmer, just got into GPGPU computing, i'm using an Nvidia Quadro 600.
I'm making a research work based on GPU programming, my aim is to write a simple Kalman Filter kernel for OpenCL using a SIMT approach. I found [this](http://www.gsi.de/informationen/wti/library/scientificreport2008/PAPERS/FAIR-EXPERIMENTS-38.pdf) document which describes the principle by how it could be done with CUDA, i think it's a similar approach for OpenCL.

The basic operations done by Kalman Filter on a linear system are three equations, each one involving matrix manipulation, which computes the Kalman Gain matrix (K), the state estimation (x~), and updates the Error Covariance matrix (P) for the next state estimation. These three steps are iterated for each measurement taken from a real system.
Considering the SIMT approach, I thought to execute one iteration of the kalman filter on each gpu thread within a thread block, i send to each thread values needed to compute the iteration (input and output from the the real system measurement, linear system matrices).

There is some better design i could consider for this algorithm to be done with OpenCL?
It is possible (and useful) to make matrix operations on a separate kernel with a parallel manner?

Another question: assume we have k iteration, for each iteration k we calculate P for the step k+1, taking as input the P for step k from iteration k-1... Since each tread compute one iteration, it is possible to synchronize thread k to wait the P matrix from thread k-1?

**UPDATE**: After many search and tries, I thought it is impossible to adapt my implementation (as described above) for this problem to the OpenCL principles of operation. The only way I found to do that is to **parallelize each single matrix operation**, maybe using more GPUs to compute each matrix operation simultaneously. Real efficiency for this implementation could be achieved with big linear system to filter (that means: it works good with big matrices).